# Request a Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

Here is my text as Entry :

```
This is An Image File [LoadImage:'image1.jpg']
this is Another Image [LoadImage:'image2.jpg']
```

I need to get `[LoadImage:'*']` start and end position(s) as an array in java

Comment: If you need position(s), you don't even need a regex here.. a simple String#indexOf() would do..

Comment: What do you mean by *position(s)*? Also, you could add a sample of the array that you are expecting.

Comment: `int[] arr = new int[]{str.indexOf('['),str.indexOf(']')}` should do.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

Comment: actually `indexOf` Return index of every `[ ]` but I need To Proccess it just if it's like `[LoadImage:'*']`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "This is An Image File [LoadImage:'image1.jpg'] this is Another Image [LoadImage:'image2.jpg']";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[LoadImage:(.*?)\\]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

'image1.jpg'

'image2.jpg'

Comment: the RegEx Not Working , just Test it please , outPut is Like this `found:  : 22 - 95=> [LoadImage:'image1.jpg'] , this is Another Image [LoadImage:'image2.jpg']`

Answer (score 1):

Is this you are looking for? If yes then use grouping feature of regex that is grouped by using parenthesis `()` and get it using `Matcher#group()` method.

Sample code:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "This is An Image File [LoadImage:'image1.jpg']",
        "this is Another Image [LoadImage:'image2.jpg']" };

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[LoadImage:.*?\\])");
for (String s : array) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(s + " : found:" + m.group(1) + " : start:" + m.start()
                + " : end:" + m.end());
    }
}
```

output:

```
This is An Image File [LoadImage:'image1.jpg'] : found:[LoadImage:'image1.jpg'] : start:22 : end:46
this is Another Image [LoadImage:'image2.jpg'] : found:[LoadImage:'image2.jpg'] : start:22 : end:46
```

Comment: Can you tell me, what you want to achieve?

Comment: As per your question you are looking for `[LoadImage:'*']`? If not then ask a question before accepting it? I never like UN-accepting an answer. Take your time first test it then accept any answer. You know there was just single change in the regex what you want to group using parenthesis that is copied by someone else. Please read the first line of my post again that might help your how regex grouping works?

Answer (score 0):

Nishant already gave you answer, but if you afraid of `[]`inside apostrophe use:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{str.indexOf('['), str.lastIndexOf(']')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex: `.*\[(.*)\]`  in group 1 is what you are looking for. Take a look here: http://fiddle.re/x9egb